# Using groupby and transform to get idxmax per week

Tags: python, pandas

**What am I trying to do?**

Get the date and time the maximum price was seen per week.

**What have I tried?**

I am trying to use `groupby` and `transform` to get `idxmax`. The output I am getting is numpy.float64 data when using `transform` with `idxmax` but when I use `idxmax` on the df it returns pandas.tslib.Timestamp data.

**Test Data:**

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=100, freq='D') 
np.random.seed(4)

stocks = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'price':(np.random.randn(100).cumsum() + 10) },index = rng)

stocks['week_id'] = pd.to_datetime(stocks.index).week #used for the groupby
```

So if I use a `groupby` to get the `max` price it returns the data I expect:

```
stocks.groupby(stocks['week_id'])['price'].transform('max')

2011-01-01    10.550513
2011-01-02    10.550513
2011-01-03    10.248203
2011-01-04    10.248203.....
```

If I then try get `idxmax` for all data:

```
stocks['price'].idxmax()
```

It return pandas.tslib.Timestamp data:

```
Timestamp('2011-03-20 00:00:00', freq='D')
```

But if I try using the via groupby and transform:

```
stocks.groupby(stocks['week_id'])['price'].transform('idxmax')
```

I get numpy.float64 data:

```
stocks.groupby(stocks['week_id'])['price'].transform('idxmax').head()

    2011-01-01    1.293926e+18
2011-01-02    1.293926e+18
2011-01-03    1.294099e+18
2011-01-04    1.294099e+18
2011-01-05    1.294099e+18
Freq: D, Name: price, dtype: float64
```

**Desired output** is a new `week_max` column as follows:

```
            price   week_id week_high   week_max
2011-01-01  10.050562   52  10.550513   2011-01-02
2011-01-02  10.550513   52  10.550513   2011-01-02
2011-01-03  9.554604    1   10.248203   2011-01-04
2011-01-04  10.248203   1   10.248203   2011-01-04
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is bug.

Alternative solution is [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html)ed `max` and `idxmax`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=15, freq='D') 
np.random.seed(4)

stocks = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'price':(np.random.randn(15).cumsum() + 10) },index = rng)

stocks['week_id'] = pd.to_datetime(stocks.index).week #used for the groupby
#print (stocks)

df1 = stocks.groupby('week_id')['price'].agg(['max', 'idxmax'])
df1.columns = ['week_high', 'week_max']
print (df1)
         week_high   week_max
week_id                      
1        10.248203 2011-01-04
2         8.668974 2011-01-14
52       10.550513 2011-01-02

print (stocks.join(df1, on='week_id'))
                price  week_id  week_high   week_max
2011-01-01  10.050562       52  10.550513 2011-01-02
2011-01-02  10.550513       52  10.550513 2011-01-02
2011-01-03   9.554604        1  10.248203 2011-01-04
2011-01-04  10.248203        1  10.248203 2011-01-04
2011-01-05   9.829901        1  10.248203 2011-01-04
2011-01-06   8.245324        1  10.248203 2011-01-04
2011-01-07   7.597617        1  10.248203 2011-01-04
2011-01-08   8.196192        1  10.248203 2011-01-04
2011-01-09   8.528442        1  10.248203 2011-01-04
2011-01-10   7.380966        2   8.668974 2011-01-14
2011-01-11   7.999635        2   8.668974 2011-01-14
2011-01-12   7.911648        2   8.668974 2011-01-14
2011-01-13   8.336721        2   8.668974 2011-01-14
2011-01-14   8.668974        2   8.668974 2011-01-14
2011-01-15   7.512158        2   8.668974 2011-01-14
```

Comment: I opend new issue in [pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15306).

Comment: Thanks you for opening the issue.  With regards to the `join` functionality.  So does this takes the smaller `df1` dataframe and expand to fit with the target `stocks` dataframe based on the `on=week_id' key?